# ImportXML "//tr/td[@class='X']" only when inside "//tr" there is also "//tr/td[@class='Y']"

Tags: regex, xpath, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

Example: The page I want to make an importXML (Google Sheets Function) has the following structure (Status & Score → Td Class):

```
<tr class=class="odd  expanded    match no-date-repetition"
   <td class="date no-repetition"
   <td class="score-time status"

<tr class=class="odd  expanded    match no-date-repetition"
   <td class="date no-repetition"
   <td class="score-time score"

<tr class=class="odd  expanded    match no-date-repetition"
   <td class="date no-repetition"
   <td class="score-time status"
```

The data that exists in td class = "date no-repetition" but without being followed by td class = "score-time status" is not necessary for what I need, I would like to know if there is any way to filter to import "home" only when inside "TR" exists "date no-repetition" and "score-time status" classes... The site has no fixed data location, so I can't work by choosing date no-repetition[1] date no-repetition[3] date no-repetition[5] to define which "home's" to import.

Comment: @player0 I updated the question to get more deal. Instead of a general example, I literally explained what I need ... [link to my sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1tJpyGFbBCpOiyyDWrKGw7iGbGg62FVWW9S3cpyJLxSw/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: @player0 The spreadsheet has already been updated for others to edit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(CONCATENATE("♦"&TEXT(REGEXEXTRACT(
 IMPORTXML(A4, A3), "\d+/\d+/\d+"), "dd/mm/yyyy")&"♦"&IMPORTXML(A4, A3)), "♦")))
```

[image]

or simple:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA({TEXT(REGEXEXTRACT(
 IMPORTXML(A4, A3), "\d+/\d+/\d+"), "dd/mm/yy"),IMPORTXML(A4, A3)})
```

[image: 0]

Comment: I found a new usage opportunity for this same function format ... But I couldn't adjust it to capture what I need ... When you have some time, could you please look what Regexextract is missing to make it work? Thank you [LinkSheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1tJpyGFbBCpOiyyDWrKGw7iGbGg62FVWW9S3cpyJLxSw/edit?usp=sharing)